# Netty Connections in TIME_WAIT

Tags: java, sockets, netty

I have created a netty server and client, which is using a Connection Factory build over DBCP, to maintain a pool of active connections. To make the connections alive, I am using keepAlive.

However, I have noticed that the sockets are increasing at a rapid rate beyond the channel pool size, because all of them are in a TIME_WAIT state.

What am I doing wrong? Is there any implementation of Channel Pool of Netty.

Answer (score 1):

There is no pool included in Netty itself. You will need to send some kind of HEARTBEAT to keep the alive. How this is implemented depends on the protocol itself. For example SMTP has a NOOP command for this.

Comment: But what I am using is when I am creating the client bootstrap, I am setting the option keepAlive as true, is that not enough.